# Steam API call failed to open stream

Tags: php, file-get-contents, steam-web-api

Hello I'm just working on a private Webpage for fun. I make a call to get a json from the steam API so that I can get the avatar of a user. Here's my code.

```
function getSteamImage() {
    $key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$key&steamids=76561197960435530');
    $json_array = json_decode($json,true);
    $image = $json_array["response"]["players"]["avatar"];
    return $image;
}

<li><img src="<?= getSteamImage() ?>"></li>
```

But now im getting this error:

> file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561197960435530):
>   failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

**BTW the Steam key I used here isn't the one I'm using in the script!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem but its not really my fault.

```
//Instead of this
$json_array["response"]["players"]["avatar"];

//It has to be this
$json_array["response"]["players"][0]["avatar"];
```

In players there is an `array` with index 0.